# Newest PCL Profile version has advantage? (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making the app with using the XF pcl.

My PCL profile is profile78.
and I somehow created new XF/pcl project.

And It's set with PCL profile111 as default now.

Is there any advantage to change my project to profile111?

And another question.
A week ago, Xamarin.forms started to support the .Net standard. Is there any advantage to using it?

Because I'm new in the .net world. Any help will help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number for PCL profiles does not mean it is newer or better. The number stands for the specific combination of platforms that is supported. With a PCL project you target a specific set of platforms and you will have a subset of the .NET Framework available to you, only the functionalities that are available on *all* the platforms you are targeting. A full list up to VS2015 Update 3 can be found [here](http://portablelibraryprofiles.apps.stephencleary.com/).

As for your question about .NET Standard, that is a whole other thing. Basically .NET Standard is aiming for true cross-platform. This means when .NET Standard version x is supported, you know you will have full access to all the features on that platform as long as it supports version x. In term it will replace the PCL.

The TL;DR from the [blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) where .NET Standard is introduced:

> .NET Standard solves the code sharing problem for .NET developers
>   across all platforms by bringing all the APIs that you expect and love
>   across the environments that you need: desktop applications, mobile
>   apps & games, and cloud services:
>
> - .NET Standard is a set of APIs that all .NET platforms have to
>     implement. This unifies the .NET platforms and prevents future
>     fragmentation.
> - .NET Standard 2.0 will be implemented by .NET
>     Framework, .NET Core, and Xamarin. For .NET Core, this will add many
>     of the existing APIs that have been requested.
> - .NET Standard 2.0
>     includes a compatibility shim for .NET Framework binaries,
>     significantly increasing the set of libraries that you can reference
>     from your .NET Standard libraries.
> - .NET Standard will replace Portable
>     Class Libraries (PCLs) as the tooling story for building
>     multi-platform .NET libraries.
> - You can see the .NET Standard API
>     definition in the [dotnet/standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) repo on GitHub.

So if you get to choose now, .NET Standard would be your best bet, but be aware that it is not fully supported yet and you may encounter some unexpected behaviour.